# How to restore repo to before last checkout

Tags: git, git-svn

I accidentally did

```
git checkout 12345
```

How can undo that and put it back to how it was before I did that? Can I do some type of reset?

Comment: please only post one question per Question, and move the other to a new post

Comment: Done, I created another issue

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout` overwrites your local file.  Git does not know the previous state, so it can't restore it.  As far as git is concerned your changes are lost.

There might be other ways to retrieve the previous version.  If you have Windows Shadow Copy enabled, that keeps track of your changes.  If your file was in Dropbox, you can revert to the earlier version on the Dropbox website.  And it can't hurt to check if your editor wrote a `12345~` or `12345.bak` file.  Some IDE's also keep a complete history, like Eclipse and the JetBrains IDE family.